# Which version of Eclipse works with PHP Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've search in vain for about a month now and I can't get my PHP application pushed to Google App Engine, for the PHP platform. I've got the Java version set up nicely on my computer. I followed the instructions for GAE PHP here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction

..but it's really confusing because it essentially tells me to install Eclipse made for PHP which is Luna, but the only versions of Eclipse that GAE supports is Kepler, Juno and Indigo  (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started), so I'm super confused.

I don't think you can install two different GAE plugins on a standard version of Eclipse (which is what I use for the Java GAE plugin).

I also tried (in vain, but it was worth a shot) to upload my app using my Java plugin/setup and obviously this was a terrible idea because all it does is just print the php script/code to the browser.

Any thoughts, brothas/sistas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out how to push php files to GAE. There are essentially 3 ways.

1. Use appcfg.py. Run following command:
   --appcfg.py update helloworld/, where helloworld is replaced by the name of the folder containing your project files. Make sure the path is relative to appcfg.py directory or an absolute path.
   --Enter your Google username and password at the prompts.

**2. Use the App Engine Launcher, probably found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher. Executable is called GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe. Simply select the project in Launcher and click Deploy.

**3. Use Git. Create a local repository on your machine. Add a repo to your Github account, and follow these instructions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy#creating_a_cloud_project

**4. Use PhPStorm. Download PHPStorm for free for 30 days, or buy a student version/whatever version you quality for here: . Then follow these instructions: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+PhpStorm+as+Google+App+Engine+PHP+IDE. The only thing I haven't figured out is #5 - where to find the php-cgi.exe file. I can't provide a path for a file I don't have.

** denotes super easy and I have used successfully.

Comment: See also: https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction

Comment: PhpStorm is by far the easiest way and most convenient way to develop for app engine. I strongly recommend (if you can afford it)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Plugin for Eclipse is only for Java applications.  For PHP applications, you'll want to use the Python/PHP SDK and either the command-line tools or the Launcher UI app for running the development server.  You can still use Eclipse for editing your PHP source files.

Comment: I'm SO glad I asked this. I never would have come to this by myself. I definitely have python installed, as it was part of the PHP set up instructions for GAE, but I don't know what commands to run or anything. Where are the instructions for how to push files to a GAE application you have already set up? Thanks so much, Dan!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this follow-up earlier. I like your answer above.

Answer (score 0):

RE #5 - "I can't provide a path for a file I don't have". 
That was also my problem.
They are fond of pointing out that the SDK directory should contain dev_appserver.py and ‘google’ and ‘php’ packages but you don't find those in a simple search cause they are invisible. You have to muck through the installation directory.